# Using a JS sourcemap directly?

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I'm aware of how to interact with the sourcemap through the browser's devtools. But can one interact with the static sourcemap directly to derive the source definition from a minimized error log?

I have the source map file: `#sourceMappingURL=6.04r8ve3g.chunk.js.map`

The error from the minified bundle reports:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'capital' of undefined
at t.value (https://.../static/js/6.04r8ve3g.chunk.js:1:286249)
```

How can I correlate the line in the error message to the actual source code line?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/source-map, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit

Comment: why did i not see that. ugh. thank you!